# Is there a way in ckeditor to change the inner html of a link?

Tags: hyperlink, ckeditor

I want to insert customs links with the link plugin of ckeditor. It already works but I want that the inner html of the anchor tag is not the link address. I followed this tutorial: http://blog.xoundboy.com/?p=393

Like so:

```
<a href="www.example.com">Click here</a>
```

Right now the inner html is the same like the href-attribute:

```
<a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
```

As far as I can tell there is no option for normal urls to do this also. But if it's possible I would appriciate a pointer in the right direction. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to type the text you want for the inner HTML, select it and then click on the link button to capture the URL ?
This way you should have your inner HTML correcty set.